# How to change display orientation in mac OS on button click

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to change the display orientation on button click event in mac OS using objective c code.

I want to implement this functionality when we open display from "System Preference" and if we select 90 then the display rotation happens and it will be displayed in portrait mode.

Image is displaying "System Preference" -> display settings:

[image: Image is attached for reference]

I have tried following code on button action but it is not working. I have included `#include <IOKit/graphics/IOGraphicsLib.h>`.

```
io_service_t service = CGDisplayIOServicePort(eDisplay); //IOKit Handle (get myDisplayID yourself)
IOOptionBits options = (0x00000400 | (kIOScaleRotate90)  << 16); //Some undocumented hex'ing
IOServiceRequestProbe(service, options); //Set rotation to display
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Does `CGDisplayIOServicePort` return `0`? Where is `eDisplay` declared and what is its value?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

eDisplay is DisplayID. I have modified the code properly. now it is working fine. 
but i have one doubt, 

'CGDisplayIOServicePort' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.9 - No longer supported 

and I am using same to get " io_service_t service = CGDisplayIOServicePort()" 

is any alternate method i need to use.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CGDisplayIOServicePort+deprecated

Comment: @Willeke Thank you for you reply.
 I have modified my code and used updated API "CGDisplayIOServiceFromPort" using this now deprecated  waring also not happening every thing is working as expected. 
But when i tried to run same code on M1 mac (whose processor is M1 chip) that time this code is not working.

Comment: Below is my code.
-(void)setOrientationWithAngle:(int)angle DisplayID:(CGDirectDisplayID) displayID {

    io_service_t service = [[NSScreen mainScreen] CGDisplayIOServiceFromPort:displayID];
    IOOptionBits options = [self angle2options:angle];
    IOServiceRequestProbe(service, options); //Set rotation to display
}

Comment: -(IOOptionBits) angle2options:(int) angle
{
    static IOOptionBits anglebits[] = {
        (kIOFBSetTransform | (kIOScaleRotate0)   << 16),
        (kIOFBSetTransform | (kIOScaleRotate90)  << 16),
        (kIOFBSetTransform | (kIOScaleRotate180) << 16),
        (kIOFBSetTransform | (kIOScaleRotate270) << 16)
    };
    
    if ((angle % 90) != 0) // Map arbitrary angles to a rotation reset
        return anglebits[0];
    
    return anglebits[(angle / 90) % 4];
}

could you please help me.